# c++ R was not declared in this scope, and unkown escape sequence '\s'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <set>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

std::string escapeChar(char ch);

std::string escapeString(const std::string& str);

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    cout << escapeString(input);
}



std::string escapeChar(char ch)
{
    if (isdigit(ch)) {
        return "\\" + string(1,ch);
    } else {
        switch (ch) {
            case '\t': return R"(\t)";
            case '\r': return R"(\r)";
            case '\n': return R"(\n)";
            case ' ': return R"(\s)";
            case '\\' : return R"(\\)";
            default: return string(1, ch);
        }
    }

}

std::string escapeString(const std::string& str) {
    std::string string = "";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        string+=escapeChar(str[i]);
    }
    return string;
}
```

This returns this compiler error

```
escapechars.cpp: In function âstd::__cxx11::string escapeChar(char)â:
escapechars.cpp:30:37: error: âRâ was not declared in this scope
             case '\t': return R("\t");
                                     ^
escapechars.cpp:33:30: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\s'
             case ' ': return "\s";
```

IT worked and run fine in my IDE, clion, but now im converting this to command line it now isnt working. So im pretty confused. stackoverflow is saying I need more details but there hoenstly arent any I think ive given all the information I can so ignore this sentence

Parameters I passed were g++ -g -std=c++14 -Wall escapechars.cpp

Comment: And what parameters you pass on command line? Are you missing `-std=c++17`?

Comment: g++ -g -std=c++14 -Wall escapechars.cpp

Comment: I never used clion but there should be a way to check what parameters it passes to compiler

Comment: It has to work with these parameters g++ -g -std=c++14 -Wall escapechars.cpp

Comment: Works for me; https://ideone.com/7sfRNg.

Comment: You need to find out what is different with your environment vs clion uses. It could be different compiler or different parameters passed by clion (or both). I doubt we can help you without knowing all of that details.

Comment: cLion uses cmake by default iirc. What's inside your CMakeLists.txt file? I assume it contains the line `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD ??)`, where ?? isn't set to 14.